# mysql error ubuntu Unknown database

Tags: mysql, linux, connection

I am a beginner in linux, I have installed mysql on linux and added 'khalil' as password to root user
when I want to connect :

```
mysql -u root -p khalil
```

I need to retype password, when I retype it, I have this error:

> ERROR 1049 (42000) : unknown Database 'khalil'

I have the same error when I want to connect to phpmyadmin

## 1045 Cannot log in to the MySQL server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command is

```
mysql -u root -pkhalil
```

Mind the missing space after `-p`

However, using a password on the command line can be dangerous (like mysql will warn you too), so consider using

```
mysql -u root -p
```

and type the password once you are prompted to.